# ubuntu apache2 start, stop, status, restart and reload commands fails

Tags: installation, apache2, webserver, lamp

Hi, I am new to Ubuntu and I'm still trying to figure this OS out (for work it's brilliant, better than Windows). Before I wrote this question, I did my research via Google, this website and even in StackOverflow.com.

Whatever error came up, I googled it but with no success on how to solve this. Back to the main point: I tried to install (lamp) apache2 with [this guide (in German)](http://www.mypcsupport.de/net/linux/ubuntu-lamp-installation/) and [this one(in english)](http://www.howtoforge.com/ubuntu_lamp_for_newbies).

Then I got stuck at the `start` command (with which one is able to start the apache2 server), my first try to run the server was a success until i wrote `sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 reload` then it showed me an error:

```
$ sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 reload
* Starting web server apache2
 Syntax error on line 1 of /etc/apache2/ports.conf:
 Invalid command 'oder', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration
 Action 'reload' failed.
 The Apache error log may have more information.
[fail]
```

I didn't even write the word "oder" so I closed the shell and opened it anew. It showed the same error. After that, I've done some research and found out that my file (index.html (which is in my /var/www folder)), which I access via the browser, when I type in `http://localhost` should show up and tell that it was a success. So I removed apache2 and installed it again but now the following errors appear:

```
$ sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 start
* Starting web server apache2
 Syntax error on line 1 of /etc/apache2/ports.conf:
 Invalid command 'oder', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration
 Action 'start' failed.
 The Apache error log may have more information.
[fail]
```

And still, I didn't even write "oder" in the command.

I appreciate every help I can get, further thanks and have a nice day.

Answer (score 1):

As the error message says there is an error in the first line of the file `/etc/apache2/ports.conf`: The word `oder` isn't allowed there.

If you can't figure it it our yourself please edit your question and include the content of that file.